# pdf-redactor syntax for URL replacement

Tags: python, pdf

Using https://github.com/JoshData/pdf-redactor
if I provide a PDF with multiple URL links and use the example code:

```
options.link_filters = [
    lambda href, annotation : "https://www.google.com" 
]
```

the effect is to change every single URL in the PDF to `https://www.google.com`

How can I get it to only replace, for example, `https://www.example.com` with `https://www.google.com` and leave the other URLs untouched?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the implementation of the redactor here https://github.com/JoshData/pdf-redactor/blob/master/pdf_redactor.py#L831 it seems like that you cant get a 'replace once' behaviour.

Comment: As `href` is the original URL, then the body can be written as `google if href == example else href`. i.e. the filter becomes an identity except for the desired URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can do a lot with that `lambda` in that lib. In this specific case you gave us, anything you insert in that function will have *https://www.google.com* as and output.

But if you want to make something different from that you can use either the URL (`href`) or the `annotation` (or both!) as parameters to change the URLs in the document. I will present to you a way you can change multiple URLs at once:

```
options.link_filters = [lambda href, annotation: 
'www.google.com' if href == 'www.example.com' else 
'www.anything.com' if href == 'www.whatever.com' else 
'www.nevermind.com' if href  == 'www.bye.com' else href]
```

Here, if you can replace all occurencies of *www.example.com* for *www.google.com*, *www.whatever.com* for *www.anything.com*, *www.bye.com* for *www.nevermind.com* and keep all the other URLs. You can even pass those URLs as variables if you ever need to make things a little bit more dynamic.

If you want to remove all the other URLs that aren't one of those three (example, whatever and bye.com), you can just replace `href` for `None` at the end of the code above.

Well, I think we both agree that the `pdf_redactor` guy should spend a little more time working on documentation. :)

Comment: Thanks. That works. I agree that the documentation leaves a lot to be desired, but it's still a good little tool.